# Doctrine - Deleting and immediately adding entities to an ArrayCollection

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an import-script which reads out a XML-File and adds data to a MySQL Database.
The xml-file contains Match-Data and associated events.

I have the following entities

- MatchList (Not the best name, but other topic)
- MatchEvent

The relevant relationship for my question:

Inside MatchList (inverse side)

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="MatchEvent", mappedBy="match", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $events;

public function __construct($uId)
{
    $this->setId($uId);
    $this->events = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Inside MatchEvent (owning side)

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="MatchList", inversedBy="events")
 * @JoinColumn(name="match_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $match;
```

Inside the import-script I have a loop for each match. Inside the loop I want to delete all events that are currently assigned to that match. And right after I want to add new events from the xml-file to this match.

The events should be completely deleted from the database. Not only the reference to the match.

A simplified example

XML-Content

```
Match1
  EventA
  EventC
  EventF
```

Before Import

```
Match1
  EventA
  EventB
```

After Import it should be like this

```
Match1
  EventA
  EventC
  EventF
```

So an event could be

- delete+add (EventA).
- delete (EventB)
- add (EventF)

This is because the XML contains updates or correction for an event. 
Therefore the only reliable way is deleting all assigned events and adding the currently valid events from the latest xml.

My problem is the deleting part In conjunction with immediately adding. Each task for it's own is working.

I tried different methods (also reading the doctrine documentation) but I'm not able to get it work.

Following the relevant part of the Script with some variants that I tried (comment out)
(Not the whole code. Look at "..." I hope this is enough to understand my problem/mistake)

```
try
{
    foreach($matches as $matchNode)
    {
        $match = new \MatchList($matchNode['uID']);
        ...
        $previousEvents = $match->getEvents();
        foreach($previousEvents as $previousEvent)
        {
            $match->removeEvent($previousEvent);
            //$previousEvent->setMatch(null);
            //$this->em->remove($previousEvent);
            //$this->em->persist($previousEvent);
        }

        foreach($teamData->Goal as $goal)
        {
            ...
            $event = new \MatchEvent($match);
            $event->setPlayer($player);
            $event->setType($goal['Type']);
            $event->setPeriod($goal['Period']);

            $this->em->persist($event);
            $match->addEvent($event);
        }
        ...
        $this->em->persist($match);
    }
    $this->em->flush();
}
catch(Exception $e){}
```

No matter what I have tried it never worked as expected. Sometimes I get an error (Missing cascade persist) or no error occurs but also no deletion. Only when I do one tasks at once (delete or add) it works.

I know that changes that are only made to the inverse side are not saved by doctrine, so I tried to call remove on the MatchEvent entities. Or tried to unset the whole ArrayCollection and with orphanRemoval also delete the entities.

I'm stuck with trying.
I hope someone can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong and what would the right way.

Thank you

**Edit**

Maybe it's helpful to add every variation I've tried.

**Variant 1)**

Without add entities right after : Remove events from DB (GOOD)

With add entities right after: ERROR: A new entity was found through the relationship 'MatchList#events' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: MatchEvent@XYZ. (BAD)

```
$previousEvents = $match->getEvents();
foreach($previousEvents as $previousEvent)
{
    $this->em->remove($previousEvent);
}
```

**Variant 2)**

Without add entities right after: Remove events from DB (GOOD)

With add entities right after: ERROR: A new entity was found through the relationship 'MatchList#events' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: MatchEvent@XYZ. (BAD)

```
$previousEvents = $match->getEvents();
foreach($previousEvents as $previousEvent)
{
     $previousEvent->setMatch(null);
     $this->em->remove($previousEvent);
     $this->em->detach($previousEvent);
}
```

**Variant 3)**

Without add entities right after: Error: A new entity was found through the relationship 'MatchList#events' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: MatchEvent@XYZ. (BAD)

With add entities right after: Not tried because not even the deletion has worked.

```
$previousEvents = $match->getEvents();
foreach($previousEvents as $previousEvent)
{
     $previousEvent->setMatch(null);
     $this->em->detach($previousEvent);
}
```

This should work or I missunderstood this:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#i-call-clear-on-a-one-to-many-collection-but-the-entities-are-not-deleted

**Variant 4)**

Without add entities right after: Doubled data in DB because no event was deleted and all the events additional insert with match_id NULL. (BAD)

With add entities right after: Not tried because not even the deletion has worked.

```
$previousEvents = $match->getEvents();
foreach($previousEvents as $previousEvent)
{
     $previousEvent->setMatch(null);
     $this->em->detach($previousEvent);
     $this->em->persist($previousEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution.

For this solution it's important to add "orphanRemoval=true".

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="MatchEvent", mappedBy="match", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $events;
```

In a loop I delete each entity from the ArrayCollection using removeElement. Because orphanRemoval is true, the entity is also deleted.

```
foreach($match->getEvents() as $event)
{
    $match->getEvents()->removeElement($event);
}
```

The adding of Entities is the same as shown above.

I hope the explanation helps others with the same problem.